# iOS stroke layer outside of it's bounds

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, calayer, quartz-core

I'm trying to build a category method on `UIView` to allow to stroke the `UIView`, similarly to the Photoshop function: **Stroke-Outside**. While `CALayer` properties borderWidth and borderColor work flawlessly to stroke on the inside, I cannot find a good way to stroke the view on the outside.

**This is the solution I came up at first:**

*Using sublayers I add another `CALayer` with frame larger than the superlayer's bounds. The layer is then inserted in the `UIView`'s sublayers.*

```
- (void)strokeViewWithColor:(UIColor *)color borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth
{
    CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CGRect borderFrame = CGRectMake(-borderWidth, -borderWidth, (self.frame.size.width) + (borderWidth * 2), (self.frame.size.height) + (borderWidth * 2));
    [borderLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [borderLayer setFrame:borderFrame];

    //
    // Copy current border layer radius
    //
    [borderLayer setCornerRadius:self.layer.cornerRadius];

    [borderLayer setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
    [borderLayer setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];

    [self.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
}
```

This works for all the `UIView`'s that have layer's property `masksToBounds` or view's property `clipsToBounds` set to `NO`. But this disables the functionality to use cornerRadius property, which I want to have.

**So my second attempt was to use `UIView`'s, since obviously I must go out of the view I want to stroke (the same logic could be applied to layer and superlayer relationship I assume).**

I came up with this solution:

```
- (void)strokeViewWithColor:(UIColor *)color borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth
{
    UIView* superview = self.superview;

    //
    // Fix frame
    //

    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.x -= borderWidth;
    frame.origin.y -= borderWidth;
    frame.size.width += (2 * borderWidth);
    frame.size.height += (2 * borderWidth);

    UIView* strokeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    strokeView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    strokeView.layer.cornerRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius + borderWidth;
    strokeView.layer.borderColor = [color CGColor];

    [superview insertSubview:strokeView aboveSubview:self];
}
```

This works, but the problem would be with auto layout. Because the `strokeView` has no auto layout constraints, it probably would not work correctly when constraints are added.

That is why I am looking for any other solutions.

**What would be the best way to solve this problem? Should I write some code to handle the auto layout issue on second part of the code? Or should I approach the problem from different perspective? If so, how?**

*I'm mostly looking for suggestions on how to approach the problem.*

Thanks for help!